# Sync Outlook 2007 tasks with gmail tasks

Tags: gmail, outlook-2007

Is there anyway, that tasks that are in Gmail can be synchronised with Outlook 2007.
Cheers
John

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. [Here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=0cf4489e6e69bd34&hl=en) is a thread of over 500 people wishing for the same thing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using Microsoft Sync framework and IMAP you can build a sync provider for gmail, and then let the framework do the job.

Read more about the Sync framework here: [Sync Microsoft Outlook with my own data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372267/sync-microsoft-outlook-with-my-own-data)