# How to write a custom sync provider for Outlook Contacts?

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, microsoft-sync-framework

Can anyone point me to an example of an Outlook Contact custom sync provider for the Microsoft Sync Framework?  I would like to use that Framework to build a bidirectional sync between my CRM and Outlook.  I've found a reference to this SO question: [Sync Microsoft Outlook with my own data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372267/sync-microsoft-outlook-with-my-own-data) 
Unfortunately, the link to MSDN example is no longer valid.  It simply redirects to the MSDN sample gallery which has no such sample.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am very curious to what the link was to, as well. I have not found anything short of either a ["Wrapped PST Store"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff960442.aspx) or "Custom MAPI Store" or "Custom MAPI Transport Provider". MAPI itself provides [a synchronization process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff960320.aspx), but it is not designed to be used from managed code and is very complicated.

The best "roundup" I have found is the [Outlook MAPI Samples](http://ol2010mapisamples.codeplex.com/) on codeplex. These do not deal with any pretty "Sync Framework" though; presumably that is used as the back-end? (Most samples neglect *how* to get to the back-end processing.)

We are evaluating an entirely managed in-Addin synchronization process here to avoid having to deal with the complications of MAPI, but the viability is still not entirely known. (This approach also introduces different problems and limitations.)

Good luck and happy coding.

Comment: Thanks pst.  Nice to know others are equally frustrated.  Misery love company, but not as much as a working sample.